# how can I use oninput without keyboard or mouseclick once there is a number entered inside my input that's driven by code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm enetering input digits with my javascript and I want to activate a function every time there is a digit change (driven by javascript) inside on of my inputs without using keyboard or mouseclick.
how can I do that? :)

```
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="recLock justify-content-center">
     <input oninput="finalCodeCheck(this)" type="text" maxlength="1" name="dig0" placeholder="*">
     <input oninput="finalCodeCheck(this)" type="text" maxlength="1" name="dig1" placeholder="*">
     <input oninput="finalCodeCheck(this)" type="text" maxlength="1" name="dig2" placeholder="*">
     <input oninput="finalCodeCheck(this)" type="text" maxlength="1" name="dig3" placeholder="*">
     <input oninput="finalCodeCheck(this)" type="text" maxlength="1" name="dig4" placeholder="*">
     <input oninput="finalCodeCheck(this)" type="text" maxlength="1" name="dig5" placeholder="*">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `change` event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: Assuming that by 'driven by javascript' you mean that you want to fire the event when you programmatically change the value get a reference to the element then call `oninput()`. Better still, attach unobtrusive events by class to DRY up your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Write something in the text field to trigger a function.</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
    }
</script>
```